# Importing 3dxml file with trimesh

Tags: python, 3d, trimesh

I try to load a 3dxml file with the python library trimesh, I want to open it and get all the meshes from it.
But I cannot load it.

I tried:
`

```
import numpy as np
import trimesh
import trimesh.path.exchange
import lxml
mesh=trimesh.load("test.3dxml")
```

`
but it returned :

> *File type: 3dxml not supported*

The documentation says it can do it :

> "Import meshes from binary/ASCII STL, Wavefront OBJ, ASCII OFF, binary/ASCII PLY, GLTF/GLB 2.0, 3MF, XAML, 3DXML, etc." [link](https://trimsh.org/index.html)

I found in the documentation a function that is supposed to do it but I cannot wrap my head around how it works: [text](https://trimsh.org/trimesh.exchange.threedxml.html?highlight=3dxml)

Does anyone know how to proceed?

Tank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You need the `lxml` package to load 3DXML/XAML/3MF files with trimesh.

So just `pip install lxml` and it should work.